# Django Rest Framework - limit ForeingKey field queryset on OPTIONS?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Calling OPTIONS on a ViewSet will render a nice presentation of the entity to help build a form to submit it on UI. Yet, when there is a ForeignKey relationship it will try to render all available entities for this relationship. I though only need a specific subset to be selectable. Is there a way to limit this field queryset like in Django Forms (by setting `form.field.queryset` attribute)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django REST framework 3, you can set [the `queryset` argument](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#the-queryset-argument) directly on the field to control what objects are allowed to be selected.

For automatically generated fields, this usually ends up being `Model.objects.all()`.  You can confirm this by calling `repr(YourSerializer())` and seeing what the automatically generated field looks like.  You can override this on automatically generated fields by setting the queryset [in `extra_kwargs`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) on the serializer level.

Comment: so if I wanted the queryset be something like `Model.objects.exclude(id=self.id)` how would I reference the self?

Comment: @abolotnov you can define a serializer field class, and set the `get_queryset` method, there, u can access the self.parent or something else..